# Unable to call a function while using master page in Javascript at checkbox checked change event

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I was trying to call a function when the checkbox status changes, it calls without a masterpage. I have tried the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#cbOption1').on('change', PublishToPreferredZerker);
  });
  function PublishToPreferredZerker() {}
</script>
[...]
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbOption1" runat="server" style="text-align: left"
  Text="Publish the job to particular Zerker or a group of the Zerkers." /><br />
```

The function is not called when using MasterPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got success while I added below code on **Page load** function.

```
cbOption1.Attributes.Add("onChange", "javascript:PublishToPreferredZerker()");
```

**Javascript function**

```
function PublishToPreferredZerker() {}
```

Also I have tried above answers but not get required output.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Note `cbOption1` is not the client ID, but the ID for the server side.

You need to do something like (Use *[Control.ClientID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)* to get the id for HTML element):

```
$('#<%=cbOption1.ClientID%>').on('change', PublishToPreferredZerker);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

`$('#cbOption1').on('change', PublishToPreferredZerker`);

finds the control with id cbOption1 and then acts on that control

But when using this code on a master page, the control id does not remain cbOption1.

It is prefixed by master page content Id.

something like ct$001cbOption1

To make it work when using master pages use code like this to find the clientId for the control :

```
$(#"<%= cbOption1.ClientID %>").on( .... )
```